# RSS for unanswered+tagged questions?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, feed

Just finished organizing regular tagged feeds and was wondering - is there a feeds for unanswered questions in specified tags?

Somehow didn't find them. :/

Comment: Not an exact RSS feed, but my frontend has some sorting/filtering capabilities for unansweredness (e.g zero answers): http://code.google.com/p/open-so-frontend/

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is! I have written a small application that does this. It's called [stack2rss](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) and it works by converting API request results into RSS feeds.

The general format for a feed that does what you describe is:

> `http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/{site}/questions/unanswered?tagged={tags}&body=true`

An example that displays unanswered questions tagged `'windows'` on SuperUser:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/superuser/questions/unanswered?tagged=windows&body=true