# Will there ever be a "Network Profile" user feed?

Tags: feature-request, users, feed

I love the user feed option for keeping up on SO sites without having the tab open all day, but it would be even better if I only had to manage one subscription, rather than adding another RSS feed to my reader every time I come across a site I want to participate in.

Comment: I doubt that RSS will ever be updated, I put in a feature request about a year ago for more RSS feeds but all I got was an app that didn't work for me and 0 official response. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed