# RSS feed issue with edited questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, feed

I think there's an issue with the current RSS feeds where a question is re-added to the feed when the title or other content is edited. I have a few feeds on tags such as `emacs` which started getting significant increase in traffic recently. On viewing some of the items they all had recently been edited.

I saw a reference to this specific bug having been fixed in [the RSS overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed) question, however the behavior still seems to be occurring.

Here's an example of one of the older items the popped back into the RSS after a title edit: [Emacs question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129476/emacs-in-place-filename-path-insertion)

Feed URL being used:
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/emacs

RSS reader: [Google Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Reader)

Comment: This still seems to be the case: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6143820#6143820 ff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get around this by using a tool I have created called [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com). This tool will generate an RSS feed from an API route.

In your case, you want a feed that contains questions tagged [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs) but you do not want question edits to show up. Therefore, the URL for your feed would be:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/questions?tagged=emacs&sort=creation&body=true

This will result in *only new questions* showing up in the feed.

Comment: I ended up deleting the feed long before any answers were posted.  Forgot about the question & didn't check back here for answers until I saw I had some meta rep for some reason :-)  Thanks for the reply & workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The default for the tag feeds is to sort by the last activity date.

If you want a different sort order, go to [the questions list for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/emacs), and then use the feed link on that page to get the ordering you're after:

- [Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs?sort=newest) - [Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=emacs&sort=newest)
- [Active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs?sort=active) - [Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/emacs)
- [Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs?sort=votes) - [Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=emacs&sort=votes)
- [Featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs?sort=featured) - [Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=emacs&sort=featured)
  ...

Finally note that each feed item includes both the "published" (created) date, and the "updated" (last-modified) date ([George's work-around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105516/rss-feed-issue-with-edited-questions/111244#111244) includes only published). So if your feed reader sorts by the latter, but you add the "newest" feed you'll get something of a cross between Newest and Active.