# RSS feeds at stack2rss not working since May 12th

Tags: support, bug, feed

My RSS reader is set to fetch this RSS feed:
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?body=true However, it hasn't been working since May 12th.

It appears that the entire stack2rss subdomain is unavailable.

Was this feature purposefully removed?

Comment: [As per this](http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source), it shouldn't have been working since the API V2 was launched, which I think was last year.

Comment: Almost right, @Asheesh, its support was only stopped May 12, the day that notice was added; see [the revision history](http://stackapps.com/posts/1599/revisions). And  [as per this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed/104673#104673) maybe SE could support a bit more ;-)